# Image animation without mouse events Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm sorry if this is a weird or noob question.

But I'm searching and searching and can't find an answer to what i'm looking for.

So far, I have a website:

[Test Website](http://tuespacioweb.com.ve/es/)

Which is using the OnePageScroll Jquery Plugin [GitHub Page](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll)

However, If you visit my website, you see there are some events on the images, which are triggered by mousevents ie: `mouseenter, hover, mouseleave`

Now, I need to know, if there is a way on Jquery to make these animations work without the mouse events, just when I scroll down or up, the animate independently from mouse or touch or other events, It will be like an automatic animation, Is this possible?

Maybe not, but who knows, I hope I've explained myself and that somebody can shed some light on this.

Thanks in advance!

PS = If you need the code let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can e.g. use [jquery.inview](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview) to start the animation as soon as an element that should be animated is in view when scrolled down.

Example usage from there:

```
$('div').bind('inview', function(event, isInView, visiblePartX, visiblePartY) {
  if (isInView) {
    // element is now visible in the viewport
   if (visiblePartY == 'top') {
     // top part of element is visible
   } else if (visiblePartY == 'bottom') {
     // bottom part of element is visible
   } else {
    // whole part of element is visible
   }
  } else {
   // element has gone out of viewport
  }
});
```

Just a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/umhtp5d7/) I used in another answer as example for inview - when you scroll down, the dial get's animated as soon as an element to which inview is bound is in view.

Comment: Super awesome! Let me try it!